# Get Woocommerce CoCart API response(add, update, delete) after promotion applied

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I would like to get the responses of each route (add to cart, update cart and delete cart) already applied to the promotion. What I face now is it only response the before promotion data. I can get the already promotion applied data by calling get cart API but I don't want to call another request to reduce the delay time.

The plugin I use for promotion is WooCommerce Discount Rules and we have promotion like (bulk discount, buy x get x, buy x get y). These rules work fine in WooCommerce Cart System but not to the Headless CoCart Lite API plugin.

How can I solve the problem, please help me if anyone have idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CoCart Lite API v2 then with every cart request you will get the cart updated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31711442)

Comment: Yes, Sébastien. Thanks for the response. It's updated on every "Get" cart request. Currently most of my APIs are slow because of plugins so I think if it could possible, the updated cart response (including discount) on every (UPDATE, DELETE) API response. But we use 2 API routes instead now and the response are correct.